# Два контроллера на один View: Java + SceneBuilder

Tags: java, mvc, наследование

Здравствуйте. 
Есть view с огромной кучей элементов. На него можно навесить один контроллер. Вместо того что бы писать громадный нечитабельный контроллер, я решил разбить его на несколько мелких. Например:

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class MainController extends B{}
```

И потом вешать MainController (в котором поля и методы контроллеров A и B) на view.
Правильно ли вообще использовать наследование по такой цепи и можно ли как то объединить несколько классов в один по другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, вы можете написать один контроллер с наследованием, с перегрузкой методов как вам вздумается, но есть одно но:

При проектировании интерфейса на JavaFX я ни разу не встречал такого. Почти во всех случаях целесообразнее не писать один большой контроллер, а разбить вашу `view` на несколько составных частей и работать с каждой по отдельности. Тогда и сами `fxml` формы получаются более красивыми и понятными, и стили навесить будет проще, и контроллеры будут выглядеть стройнее и логичнее.